# Create a ruby method that accepts a hash of parameters and adds them to my method's hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def n(options={a: 1, b: 2})
  ...
end

n(c: 3)
```

Hey guys. How can I add {c: 3} pair to my method's hash, without replacing all hash? I want to receive options={a: 1, b: 2, c: 3} in my method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to override your options, you can do it using [`Hash#reverse_merge`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-reverse_merge) method:

```
def n(options = {})
  opts = options.reverse_merge(a: 1, b: 2)
  # ...
end
```

Comment: `Hash#reverse_merge!` should be the only way! The `||=` method unfortunately overrides nil and false values, so it's unsafe for that reason.

Comment: I'd suggest `options = options.reverse_merge ...` instead of `options.reverse_merge!` as a general practice. With the bang method, if the method is called on an options hash in the parent scope that hash will be modified as a side effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
def n(options={})
  options.merge!{a: 1, b: 2} 
  ...
end

n(c: 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, since Ruby 2.0, you can use double-splat operator argument to catch all unspecified method arguments:

```
def n(options={a: 1, b: 2}, **extra)
  ...
end

n(c: 3)  # options={a: 1, b: 2}, extra = {c: 3}
n(options={a:11, b: 99}, c: 123)  # options={a: 11, b: 99}, extra = {c: 123}
```

You would need to merge/update received hashes to get it all in one, though.